# Add textbox text to new string in list each time button is pressed

Tags: c#, string, list, text

This is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> user = new List<string>();

        user.Add(usertextBox.Text);
```

I want it where each time I press the button, whatever is in usertextBox at that point gets added to the list 'user' as a new item, so I can recall the different ones later with [1], [2], [3], etc. I also want it so the user can close the app and all the users will still be saved. I I don't know if C# does this automatically

Even if you can only answer one of my questions that's fine. Thanks!!

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? WPF? WP7? SilverLight? Metro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are making `List` local to Button that means every time you click button new object of `List` is created, You should create it out side button click method. Try this.

```
List<string> user = new List<string>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        user.Add(usertextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Going off of jams answer, you should probably declare `private List<string> user = new List<string>();`

Comment: @Gabriel Graves: what is your meaning? sorry I did not get your point.

Comment: @Gabriel Graves: your comment was for me or it was for HW90 ?

Comment: sweet this works, thanks a lot! i'll try to figure out saving the data in the list

Comment: @GabrielGraves: If there is no modifier specified as in jams answer then it automatically becomes `private`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Sorry, I was trying to do it proper even though I guess proper could be leaving `private` off as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `List` out side of the method. C# does not keep the content of the list.

```
 private List<string> user = new List<string>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            user.Add(usertextBox.Text);
    }
```

for saving the content you could use a database (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655884%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or an xml file (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7718/Using-XML-in-C-in-the-simplest-way).

to save the content of the List you could create a new class containing this two methods instead of the list

```
public List<string> getListContent()
      {
          //read xml-file
      }
      public void Add(string t)
      {
          //write to xml file
      }
```

This will just fine work in single thread applications.

Comment: I like how this answer got downvoted and it's identical to the one that got accepted.